# Resource (room) response status when creating a event Microsoft Graph Calendar

Tags: node.js, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently working on Office 365, i want my mobile application to be able to book rooms.

I'm using Microsoft Graph which is great by i'm a little confused about this route : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_post_events

It seems that it is not possible to directly know if the room is accepted.

Request :

```
{
"end": {
  "dateTime": "2018-05-11T12:10:10",
  "timeZone": "Europe/London"
},
"attendees": [{
    "type": "resource",
    "emailAddress": { "address": "berlin@bapflex.onmicrosoft.com"}
}],
"location": {"locationType": "conferenceRoom","locationEmailAddress": "berlin@bapflex.onmicrosoft.com"},
"start": {
  "dateTime": "2018-05-11T10:10:10",
  "timeZone": "Europe/London"
},
"subject": "Subject",
"responseRequested": true
}
```

I'm getting an response where i'm told that the event is created.
By i get the responsestatus of the room afterwards , whether its rejected or accepted.

Is this normal way ? or is there any toggle variable to wait the organizer to send me the response of the room?

Thx

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying you're getting a response from the room or you're not getting a response from the room? It also isn't clear what you mean by waiting on the organizer to send your something.

Comment: I'm sorry i was not clear. The response says that the meeting is created. So a meeting is created in my calendar (based on the fact that I'm doing the request) But the meeting is not created on calendar's room. There is a async moment , the organizer needs to check if the room is available.

Comment: The room's invite should automatically be forwarded to its delegate to confirm (unless it's set up to auto-accept of course). Is this not happening?

Comment: Im sorry whats its delegate ?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Do you know if the beta version will become a v2 soon ?

Comment: A delegate is someone assigned to manage a given mailbox on that mailbox owner's behalf.

Comment: Beta doesn't mean "coming in v2.0". Each endpoint/feature is released on their own cafence and every month different items roll out of `/beta/` and into `/v1.0/`.

Comment: The idea, behind my question, is there any way of knowing what you work on by priority and if it is doable to make the /findRooms route work in prod

Answer (score 1):

The event is created in your own calendar. Follow up your create request with a call to the me/calendarview API. In the array of attendees you will see the status:

```
"attendees": [
                {
                    "type": "resource",
                    "status": {
                        "response": "accepted",
                        "time": "2018-04-18T23:00:16.8237034Z"
                    },
```

The status will be tentativelyAccepted until the room/delegate accepts or declines your invitation.

I also noticed that the you can't see the response of the resource unless you are the organizer. For some reason, if you're just one of the other attendees, the resource response is missing. I don't know why that is.

Comment: Thank you ! Do i have to make some long polling stuff to wait to get a refused or accepted response ? Or is there any hoook ?

Comment: I don’t know of any web hook available. In my case, I’m polling anyway to periodically refresh a view of the room schedule.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks ?